# Typescript class implementation patterns

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to use classes more often and so I generated an `interface` and `class` for a model:

```
export interface IIndexClient {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  user_id?: number;
  location_id?: number;
  mindbody_id?: number;
  appointment_type?: string;
  found?: boolean;
  time?: string;
  status?: string;
  submitted?: boolean;
  consult_status?: boolean;
  consultation_id?: number;
  consultation?: IConsultation;
}

export class IndexClient implements IIndexClient {
  public id?: number;
  public name?: string;
  public user_id?: number;
  public location_id?: number;
  public mindbody_id?: number;
  public appointment_type?: string;
  public found?: boolean;
  public time?: string;
  public status?: string;
  public submitted?: boolean;
  public consult_status?: boolean;
  public consultation_id?: number;
  public consultation?: IConsultation;

  constructor( data: Partial<IIndexClient>,
               private locationService ) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }

  getLocationName() : string {
    return this.locationService.locations.filter((loc) => loc.id == this.location_id)[0].name
  }
```

I need to be able to use the `getLocationName()` function but it requires an instance of `LocationService` in order to have access to `locations`.  The issue is that now when I create an instance of an `IndexClient` I need to include the `LocationService`:

```
this.client = new IndexClient(this.client, this.locationService);
```

Is there some way to have access to a provider's value inside my `IndexClient` class without having to provide it each time?

Comment: Why do you need that interface?

Comment: And you could pass that service to the method, store it in a static property, in a variable ...

Comment: You probably want to use [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) or some dependency injection framework.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting solution.

https://nehalist.io/dependency-injection-in-typescript/

I'm hope you find it interest too.

Regards.